# Cannot create external table. External table location already exists?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse-analytics

I am using the serverless sql feature in ASA to write the parquet file that I've stored onto a database that I can read. I know the only way you can do this is to use CETAS which I am doing but when I run this SQL statement.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AW_data
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'xxx/output/',
    DATA_SOURCE = BlobStorage,
    FILE_FORMAT = Parquet_file
)  
AS
 SELECT *
 FROM  
     OPENROWSET(
         BULK 'xxx/output/AW.parquet',
         DATA_SOURCE = 'BlobStorage',
         FORMAT='PARQUET'
     ) AS result;
```

I get this error

> Cannot create external table. External table location already exists. Location Provided: 'https:...

Why do I get this error and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as the above query might have been executed once already thereby creating a folder in the path :
LOCATION = 'xxx/output/'

for you to re execute this query, you need to delete the folder output.